# How to modify the Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) email notification template?

Tags: azure-devops

Visual Studio Team Services has a Markdown-based project documentation feature in form of a wiki.

When a user updates the wiki an email is sent to everyone who has a notification set up.

The email looks like this:

[image]

The default template includes a lot links into the code repository.

Is it possible to modify the email template that a link to the actual wiki page is also included?

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is to link Microsoft Flow or IFTTT to VSTS, send the notification to it and then use that service to craft a custom notification. The notification templates of VSTS itself are currently not customizable.